# Reading strings from text files using getline() in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, getline

I am working on the simple problem of finding the number of similar strings in two separate text (.txt) files which are named "4_1.txt" and "4_2.txt". However the getline() function in my code does not read the files as it returns the file stream '00000000' (I have checked it using 'cout'). Both the text files have been successfully opened using the ifstream.open() function. Why the getline() function is not working, and what is required for it's debugging? (I am using Visual C++ 2010). The code is-

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <string>
# include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int match = 0,individual_match=0;
    vector<int> arr_match;

    string file_name_1 = "Database/4_1.txt";
    string file_name_2 = "Database/4_2.txt";
    string s1,s2;

    ifstream ifs1(file_name_1);
    if (!ifs1)
    {
        cout<<"File 1 read error :"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    ifs1.open(file_name_1, ios::in);
    cout<<"File No. "<<file_name_1<<" succesfully opened"<<endl;
    ifstream ifs2(file_name_2);
    if (!ifs2)
    {
        std::cout<<"File 2 read error :"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    ifs2.open(file_name_2, ios::in);
    cout<<"File No. "<<file_name_2<<" succesfully opened"<<endl;


    // Matching Begins
    cout<<"Matching Between: "<<file_name_1<<" and "<<file_name_2<<endl;
    while (getline(ifs1,s1))
    {
        while (getline(ifs2,s2))
        {
            if (strcmp(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str()) == 0)
                match++;          
        }
        ifs2.clear();
        ifs2.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    }
    cout<<"No. of Matching Minutiae between "<<file_name_1<<" and "<<file_name_2<<" is : "<<match<<endl;
    arr_match.push_back(match);
    ifs2.close();

    cout<<"Printing the contents of the Vector: "<<endl;

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = arr_match.begin(); i != arr_match.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

The contents of "4_1.txt" and "4_2.txt" are given below. Both contain 20 strings (each string contains 64 HEX characters).

**4_1.txt**

f789909693b3898605450349b35d0218bc556c51f960f944e50ae242dc3446a3
b780f20d75afc6afe44ccc270ba7e499c070a95e6535bcc71de8aa36ced3b5b6
12269c796b58fb51020e17da59733d060552b37f7916e2f97df9f9bdc0e235a0
94ca7771bcbfb3a51a6feb57e67955bf57e7655c4e38f23c42f2cb8f26bed543
290a0b92873bdf4e47986dc5208037bad7527653bff700dc53c1e57eb98103c1
5b7267c26cc279fdbe97b434c889c0ec3831f2294b19e4b8a9228de154551503
8a835b9bf9c1f8976256bf02427710f8ecf85f55aa59e5084421be8793752362
3b37ef6a1be31e06efd2f3cfa7e70d2b25d95efec97e5b71503a95e249d13250
c6fab63609e8a0b0dad162a533ce5da4d8f4d40b652c8af06c6a542f4eba74b5
61aad04aa9341a27da25994e4e72be78828a848291b781d8c19a5192b860f033
92b18972560ad2bbd2800ccd28c975279ef95f74abb8cf37298def1cb681af9e
900f7b407b5aa1f1759d248ae30e80a9e9f6d835d5d630c57330271264edc4ab
4a081bff0bf93d06ee54ff45353e8b65bce23522ae6a45769f5968ff5956356e
058b346de9b51add4eca9aec2ab0ed11aed227590421e2a05070ae1236954094
be1dfca7b57921df356fe39227da629c8ce9d04ea37b7dc109639a2cd99b127a
6ef3dcb7be11f8c49ebcf27b2bd215629cebe39577cd7a29e6005ffffb4a883d
9e3b6232cb7bd60ef9c5088e1c6dac834ddc05d916e88e2aacf84bb18c8d707a
ef13ebc3a57a1b51c17b45fcfef8eef761deab8371cc9e4eca14962d5763123d
4459b2909cef1e99ddfb4be233208753a4ed2f43343df6d5b4561c5e9ead51c9
059abcdaf2f2d2fbd6d40a18ff9e7d23db83e8ea1662b1b8d96f7ff3a189dbd0

**4_2.txt**
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Comment: your calls to `std::ifsteam::open()` is completely redundant and unnesessary

Comment: "it returns the file stream '00000000'" what does it mean? What actually did you print?

Comment: @Slava In fact, that's what the whole problem is about. The second `open` sets `failbit` to `true`.

Comment: If you want to know why, check error code. If you need your program to work remove it at all. Why did you put it there first place? And you can compare `std::string` like `if( s1 == s2 )` you do not need convoluted way with `strcmp`. And you should read one file into `std::set` or `std::map` and then compare rather than read the same file again and again.

Comment: @Slava thanks a lot. It solved the problem.